# Is it possible to use a post's custom meta value inside of functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function

I've got a wordpress site that I need to use some of the custom post's meta values inside of one of my functions in functions.php. Is this even possible? & if so, and somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using the WordPress function `get_post_meta()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

You would use it like this:

```
$array_of_your_custom_fields = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key );
```

Or

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );
// value is a single result of type string
```